# how to get current location using location services turned off

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I use the following code to get Current Location from a Network provider turn off in my application:

```
LocationManager mgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
boolean network_enabled = mgr.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
if(network_enabled){
Location location = mgr.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

This is expected from a Network provider. But the problem is:
when location services turn on its return true and finally get current location.
Suppose I turn off return false and get values 0.0,0.0.

If any other way to get current location using network provider when location service turn off?

Comment: `when location service turn off` it means that the user does not want any app to know his location, and you have no alternative to **respect the user's choice**. Only thing you can do is to get aproximate location by user's IP address, while this may be so inaccurate, that it shows even wrong city

Answer (score 0):

Use Fused Location API of Google.

https://developers.google.com/location-context/fused-location-provider/

It is more convenient. It provide last known location.

Comment: It only provides a location if location services are on.  If they're off, it doesn't work either.

Comment: Try this Fused Location Example

https://github.com/folivares/Fused-Location-Singleton